# What are the ways in which the RSA cryptosystem may be compromised even if factorisation of n is not known?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

What are the ways in which the RSA crypto-system may be compromised even if the factorization of N is not known?

It seems that the only way to break the RSA crypto-system is by getting the factors of N, but my assignment is asking me if there are others ways it can be compromised. I have done some research but I can't find any.

Comment: Pointing a gun at the owner of the private key.

Comment: The question is better suited for http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to break RSA, even if the factors have been chosen according to the best practices (modulus is strong, public exponent fulfills security criteria) and the attacker does not have any part of the secret exponent (no side channels attacks): the common module attack, the low public exponent attack, padding attacks, etc.

You can find a good summary in [Boneh's paper](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf).

Comment: The RSA OAEP padding oracle attack was covered here recently, it would make a nice example of a padding attack.